# How to add script to theme of Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to make my first theme in Wordpress step-by-step but I have problem to insert a script into it.

```
function loadingScripts(){
  wp_register_script(    'awqnimate',
     get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
                      array('jquery'),
        '1.1',
        'false');
    wp_enqueue_script('awqnimate');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadingScripts');
```

I put this in `function.php` and in index.php I have `<?php get_header(); ?>`  and `<?php footer(); ?>` as well and it work perfect. But when I go to my page and check the roots I do not see this scripts at all. Please give me feedback. I read all and cannot see my mistake.

---

update

I  change fill name and something move forwards but...

```
function loadingScripts(){
  wp_register_script(    'awqnimate',
     get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
                      array('jquery'),
        '1.1',
        'false');
    wp_enqueue_script('awqnimate');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadingScripts');
```

still do not work at all and this work but have some kind of errors Can't find variable: jQuery

````
   wp_register_script
('normwalize',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js',
        '1.1',
        'true');
                      wp_enqueue_script('normwalize'); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

File name should be `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your add_action

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'awqnimate');
```